# facebook graph api doesn't return the statuses i shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch all my facebook timeline posts throw the facebook Graph API.
I'm playing with the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and have an access token with this permissions: (user_posts, read_stream) but when i call the endpoint "/posts" or "/feed" in the graph-api, the statues i ***shared*** (not i created) on my timeline (friends public status that i shared) didn't return.

this is a screenshot from my timeline

any idea?

Comment: screenshot from my timeline: http://s21.postimg.org/pqikpvr0n/image.png

Comment: screenshot from the graph-api response http://s11.postimg.org/sf01tqojn/image.png
you will notice the post between(1&2) on my timeline didn't return in the graph-api

Answer (score 0):

If you share another `POST - status` then I dont think there is a way that will show up in your feed. It will show up under the user's feed who originally shared it, under `posts` and `sharedposts`

But if you share a `link` then it will show up under your feed as `shared_story`

Example from my feed

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXXX", 
      "from": {
        "id": "XXXXXXXX", 
        "name": "XXXXXXXX"
      }, 
      "story": "Vrashabh Irde shared a link.", 
      "story_tags": {
        "0": [
          {
            "id": "XXXXXXXX", 
            "name": "XXXXXXXX", 
            "type": "user", 
            "offset": 0, 
            "length": 13
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAvV7MyLsxFjRDc&w=130&h=130&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F05%2Fdave-goldberg.jpg%3Fw%3D560%26h%3D292%26crop%3D1&cfs=1&sx=1&sy=0&sw=292&sh=292", 
      "link": "http://tcrn.ch/1GR0HU3", 
      "name": "Dave Goldberg, SurveyMonkey CEO, Dies Unexpectedly", 
      "caption": "tcrn.ch", 
      "description": "Silicon Valley and the wider world of technology are mourning the very sudden death of Dave Goldberg, a long time entrepreneur and investor, CEO of..", 
      "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/post.gif", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX/posts/XXXXXXXX"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX/posts/XXXXXXXX"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
        "description": "Your friends", 
        "friends": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "link", 
      "status_type": "shared_story", 
      "created_time": "2015-05-03T14:45:09+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2015-05-03T14:45:09+0000", 
      "is_hidden": false, 
      "subscribed": true
    }
```

This is from what I know, I dont see any documentation that says otherwise, good to have someone from Facebook comment here or you should probably raise a bug if this is not intended.